# Is Q-Learning ever better than Brute Force?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently learning about the [Q-learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) algorithm, so I therefore assume that it has some use or purpose. However I currently cannot see how it is in any way useful. In terms of complexity class, it appears to perform equal to or worse than brute force, which as far as I am aware, is the lowest you ever need to go to compute something computable.

What, if anything, have I missed?

Comment: "I am currently learning about the Q-learning algorithm, so I therefore assume that it has some use or purpose." -- Not necessarily. It may just be used didactically to make a point.

Comment: @Raphael Well that is a purpose then.

Comment: I'm glad you agree! :)

Comment: As it is this question doesn't make any sense. You need to define what you mean by brute force in this scenario. Are you assuming you're given all the transition probabilities and rewards probabilities beforehand (note, this is wildly different then the assumption made in scenarios where Q-learning would be applied)? How does "brute force" deal with stochastic environments? etc etc.

Comment: The brute force I had in mind would check every route possible and find the best reward, but I hadn't considered probabilistic environments, which seems to be where Q-learning wins out.

Comment: @930913 Another thing worth noting is you can use Q-learning in an online setting, which is the setup most people who study reinforcement learning are interested in.

Comment: @930913 Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: [Q-learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) / wikipedia

Answer (score 6):

Reinforcement Learning (RL) algorithms are useful in a setting when the structure of the environment is unknown and/or stochastic. The environment is normally formalized as a [Markov Decision Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) (MDP) or Partially Observable Markov Decision Process (POMDP) and the goal of an RL agent is then to maximize its cumulative reward (or minimize its regret with respect to the best alternate policy) while behaving in the environment.

As such it isn't clear how a brute force algorithm would efficiently deal with the stochastic nature of the environment or the fact that this procedure is almost universally assumed to be done online. For more information and a modern overview of RL I recommend this [excellent reference](http://www.ualberta.ca/~szepesva/papers/RLAlgsInMDPs.pdf) by Csaba Szepesvari.